# How to show brand, size, color in menu with category?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-menu

how to show products attributes with category in menu. please see this image what i want.
Any Extension or custom solution please Help me.

[image: when i click or hover any category then show like this]

Comment: create sub-categories with your desire attribute names

Comment: I will assign color, size of products .so How to show BRAND, SIZE, COLOR , etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Sub-Categories with your desired attribute names.
2. Assign products to the category(attribute) which you want.
3. For ex: if you want to add **Nokia** brand to the mobiles, select nokia (attribute) category and assign the products to this.

Comment: It's Not a Perfect SOLUTION !!!

Comment: How do you know that its not perfect solution? you have shared one screenshot right?